# @Reference not working inside the *serviceImpl of Liferay DXP

Tags: dependency-injection, liferay, osgi, liferay-7

Inside the service builder *serviceImpl class, the @Reference annotation gives a null value and there is a catch here. When the impl class first activates (inside the @activate function), the @reference annotations works. But later, when we call a method inside the service, the @reference dependency is null.

```
public interface Base{}

................

@component(service = Base.class)

public class Sample implements Base{}

..................

@Component(.......)
public class TestServiceImpl{

    @Reference
    private volatile Base b;
    
    public void doSomething(){
        
     b.test(); // null point exception
    
    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties)
    {
      b.test(); // works here 
    }
    }

}

// portlet class
    @Component(
            immediate = true,
            property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=" + somevalue,
                "mvc.command.name=" + somename
            },
            service = MVCResourceCommand.class
        )
    public class TestCommand implements MVCResourceCommand{
        
        @Override
        public boolean serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
                throws PortletException {
    
            testService.doSomething();// throws NPE becoz Base b is null inside the method
    }
    ....
    
        @Reference
        TestLocalService testService;
    ... }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried removing the `volatile` keyword? I rarely see Liferay using it

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your code is somewhat odd with random capitalization (`@component`) and the `@Component` annotation on a method. I'm assuming that this is just a typo (though I wonder why you're not just copying/pasting your questionable code into your question.

`@Reference` is always resolved for a container-managed `@Component`. However, it's possible that you create one of those objects yourself - in that case:

1. don't do that
2. it's your responsibility to set up the object

Another possible cause is that you might have saved some `@Component`-annotated object yourself, and it has already been undeployed. You should also not do that, as it might mean that its `@Reference`s are invalidated/nulled.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry about the capitalization issues and code quality. This was just a quick mock-up code I created here to reflect the actual scenario simplified.

I didn't create the Component object myself. This was a service builder class. I used this service builder in a portlet command class. In this portlet, I used @Reference to inject the service builder and tried to use a function inside it. Also, all the required modules are deployed.

Most interesting thing is that the Reference works inside the Activate method of the service builder and not outside.

Comment: validate if you are in _exactly_ the same, identical, object. I suspect that you (or someone) instantiate the object yourself, which bypasses OSGi's initialization

Comment: I validated that the object is not created by ourselves. It's managed by the OSGi, and also it's a very simple code structure. I edited the original question with the portlet class that uses this service builder.

Comment: In that case, please provide a [mcve]. Also, mention the _exact_ version names and steps to reproduce